# Getting all projectname values with certain name in a table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I am creating a website for me and my friends so we can work on projects with each other (Like Google documents), and I am trying to create a thing so we can choose what project we want to work on. Currently I am having trouble getting the names of the projects from the MySQL table.

Here is what I have tried to get the names of the projects

```
$projects = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='". $username ."'");
$projects2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($projects);
$projects3 = $projects2["projectname"];
```

And here is an example of the MySQL table

```
+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------
-+
| name    | htmltext         | csstext          | jstext           | projectname
 |
+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------
-+
| cow9000 | testing is cool! | testing is cool! | testing is cool! | test
 |
| cow9000 | testing is cool! | testing is cool! | testing is cool! | test2
 |
+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------
```

As you can see there are 2 documents that the owner owns, but when I try printing out `$project3`, it only gives me "test". How would I change my code to get all projectname values?

Sorry if this is confusing, it is hard for me to put it into words. Also, please do point out errors in my code as I only have a couple days of experience in PHP and MySQL (But I am finding that PHP and MySQL is very, very easy for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through the returned data, for example like this:

```
while ($projects2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($projects)) {
  echo $projects2["projectname"];
}
```

First it will return `test`, second `test2`

Answer (score 2):

<s>You already have all of those values. You just access them like you did `projectname`, by using the name of that column as the key in the `$projects2` array:</s>

```
$projects2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($projects);
echo $projects2["name"]; // cow9000
echo $projects2["htmltext"]; // testing is cool!
echo $projects2["csstext"]; // testing is cool!
echo $projects2["jstext"]; // testing is cool!
```

If you want the second row you need to use a loop:

```
// Prints each row in the order they were retrieved 
while($projects2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($projects)) {
    echo $projects2["projectname"]; // test and then test2
}
```

Comment: I meant how would I get the second projectname? Sorry about that, edited my question to make it more clear.